# Is it possible to "import" a schema file in another schema file in Solr?

Tags: solr

I've got a single schema file that's grown pretty large as it has pre-defined fields for multiple languages. Not all fields will be used by all consumers (and, in fact, most will only use 1-2 languages), but we need sensible defaults for clients. It's not really *terrible* to work with, but it could be a lot easier to manage if I could divide the schema up by language.

Is it possible to have a schema file import another file? Something like,

```
<schema name="catalog-config" version="1.6">
   ...
   <import file="./lang/spanish.xml"/>
   ...
</schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`XInclude`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/).

Your schema.xml may already contain `xi:include` code chunks (to be uncommented), eg.

```
  <fields>
    <!-- regular/dynamic fields definitions... -->
  </fields>

  <xi:include href="schema_fields_spanish.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:fallback></xi:fallback>
  </xi:include>
```

You can see an example of this in Solr configuration for TYPO3 search (e.g. [for Korean](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/blob/5f6eff68db942120c5a8d923721c007dc4733c72/Resources/Private/Solr/configsets/ext_solr_11_1_0/conf/korean/schema.xml#L30)).

Note, however, that recent Solr versions use managed-schema, which gets rewritten on any change. That means all the XIncludes will get pulled-in and rearranged. If you are not happy about that and prefer to version-control your schema file, you can disable that in solrconfig.xml with [Schema Factory configuration](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html#solr-uses-managed-schema-by-default).